# Add Selected checkbox column in lookup screen and enable multi-select

Tags: acumatica

Is there a quicker or generic way to allow multiple selection from a lookup dialog ? Screen below for example - AR209500 (Discount) allows, selection of Price Class one at a time.

[image]

What I need is similar to this screen where I can add the selected records to my grid. It doesn't need to have complex filters.

[image]

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, there is no option to include a checkbox column into a lookup to simultaneously select multiple records. The Acumatica Framework provides `PXMultiSelector` control, which allows selecting several records. However with the `PXMultiSelector` you can only select one record at a time, so it gets appended to the list of previously selected records. For an example of `PXMultiSelector` you can refer to the **To**, **CC**, and **BCC** input controls on the **Email Activity** screen (**CR306015**).

If your requirement is to provide a list of records with a checkbox column to simultaneously select and process multiple records, `PXSmartPanel` with just a `PXGrid` placed in it seems to be the best and only known to me option to accomplish this.